# Java request only works when

Tags: java, http, post, request

This is my code:

```
String httpURL = "http://codespeed_server:8000/result/add/";
URL myurl = new URL(httpURL);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) myurl.openConnection();
con.setDoOutput(true);
DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
output.writeBytes(query);
```

Can anybody tell me why this only works when I trail to it:

```
con.getResponseCode();
```

? The server only gets new entries when I call *getResponseCode()*. Is it a normal behavior ? Or is it a server-side issue ?

Comment: If you take out the `con.getResponseCode()`, what happens? Show what you do after `writeBytes()`.

Comment: Out of interest, does it get written if you call `output.close()` or `output.flush()` afterwards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `URLConnection` does not make a connection until one of the `getResponse*`, `getInputStream` methods (or other method which requires response data) is called (or `connect()`).